# Simple Trampoline Hook

Tags: c, winapi

I've been attempting to write a trampoline hook on ExitProcess for fun. The hook's code (a message box) executes  fine, but when it is time to return to the ExitProcess, I get an Access Violation. I've read over my own code several times and cannot see anything wrong with it. I'm storing the old function prologue in the byte array, and adding the jmp to the address right after the address I patched at. Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
#include "main.h"

PVOID TrampolineAddress;
BYTE TrampolineBytes[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xE9, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

void ExitProcessNew(UINT uExitCode)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Exiting!", "Exiting!", 0);
    _asm 
    {
        push uExitCode;
        call TrampolineAddress;
    }
}

int main()
{
    memcpy(&TrampolineBytes, &ExitProcess, 5);
    *(DWORD*)&TrampolineBytes[6] = (DWORD)((DWORD)&ExitProcessNew) - (DWORD)&ExitProcess;

    TrampolineAddress = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 10, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(TrampolineAddress, TrampolineBytes, 10);

    BYTE PatchBytes[] = { 0xE9, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    *(DWORD*)&PatchBytes[1] = (DWORD)((DWORD)&ExitProcessNew) - (DWORD)&ExitProcess - 5;

    BOOL writeSuccess = WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), &ExitProcess, PatchBytes, sizeof(PatchBytes), NULL);

    ExitProcess(0);
    printf("%d", GetLastError());
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Please show the full error message, as well as the call stack at the point of failure. I'm not sure, but I believe the `call TrampolineAddress;` should really be `jmp TrampolineAddress;`, otherwise you have 2 calls (and 2 return addresses on the stack) in place of just one call to your replacement function `ExitProcessNew`.

Comment: **1.** you must copy not 5 byte but integer count of instructions. **2** sometimes instructions can not be moved as is, if it use relative *eip* addressing. this is most for *x64*, but in *x86* exist jmp, conditional jx - so you need analyze code at begin. **3** for what you use *_asm* block ?

Comment: @IInspectable - call trampoline functions is ok. we return back from this call, to `ExitProcessNew` (of course not in case ExitProcess but in general case). another thing that 5 bytes length is bad length in concrete case (op copy not integer instruction count)

Comment: @RbMm Hi, I used 5 bytes because supposedly WinAPI functions are hotpatchable and I was told that the first five bytes were all that was needed

Comment: @IInspectable I substituted the call for a jmp and it still crashed. The full error is `Exception thrown at 0x8AE6D90B in Hooking.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x8AE6D90B.`

Comment: no, you mistake. at first who say you that this api is hotpatchable ? at second hotpatchable api is hooked in absolute another way. first 2 bytes (`mov edi,edi`) is replaced to `jmp $-7` and in 5 bytes **before** function you insert jmp. however i exactly explain your error to you (can even not look stack trace, exception code, etc) - you can not copy **constant** count of bytes. you can not copy as is

Comment: You really should be using a pre-existing hooking library for this, such as Microsoft Detours, not trying to implement it by hand.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wanted to implement it by hand to learn how it worked

Answer (score 4):

I spent a good hour trying to get your code to work and I eventually gave up, deciding it was easier just to show you code that works rather than try to fix yours.  Your logic makes sense but I think there were a couple little mistakes causing the failure.

So here is the method I have been using for a long time, which are based on some code a friend shared with me named Solaire:

Regular Hook/Detour function:

```c++
bool Hook(BYTE* src, BYTE* dst, int len)
{
    if (len < 5) return false;

    DWORD  curProtection;
    VirtualProtect(src, len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &curProtection);

    uintptr_t  relativeAddress = ((uintptr_t)dst - (uintptr_t)src) - 5;

    *src = 0xE9;
    *(uintptr_t *)((uintptr_t)src + 1) = relativeAddress;

    VirtualProtect(src, len, curProtection, &curProtection);
    return true;
}
```

Trampoline Function:

```
void * TrampolineHook(BYTE* src, BYTE* dst, int len)
{
    // Make sure the length is greater than 5
    if (len < 5) return 0;

    // Create the gateway (len + 5 for the overwritten bytes + the jmp)
    void* gateway = VirtualAlloc(0, len + 5, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    //Write the stolen bytes into the gateway
    memcpy(gateway, src, len);

    // Get the gateway to destination addy
    uintptr_t  gatewayRelativeAddr = ((uintptr_t)src - (uintptr_t)gateway) - 5;

    // Add the jmp opcode to the end of the gateway
    *(BYTE*)((uintptr_t)gateway + len) = 0xE9;

    // Add the address to the jmp
    *(uintptr_t *)((uintptr_t)gateway + len + 1) = gatewayRelativeAddr;

    // Place the hook at the destination
    Hook(src, dst, len);

    return gateway;
}
```

You already know the logic so I don't much need to explain the code, the comments should suffice.

Now below we will typedef a function pointer matching the ExitProcess function, and prefix it with "t" for template.

Then we create pointer of that type and prefix it with "o" for original because after we run our code we will call the "original" function using it.  Then our actual function that we redirect flow to gets prefixed with "h" for "hooked" or whatever.

Main Code:

```
typedef void(__stdcall* tExitProcess)(UINT);
tExitProcess oExitProcess;

void __stdcall hExitProcess(UINT uExitCode)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Exiting!", "Exiting!", 0);
    Sleep(1000);

    return oExitProcess(uExitCode);
}

int main()
{
    oExitProcess = (tExitProcess)TrampolineHook((BYTE*)&ExitProcess, (BYTE*)&hExitProcess, 5);
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Pretty standard procedure, try it out and maybe compare it to yours and hopefully that helps