# How to Inject DLL into ANY process?

Tags: c++, windows, security, dll, process

I'm working on way to inject a dll into any process on windows.
I already have a code that work for my own program, like hello world or thing like that but other programs, like notepad , calc, chrome, etc..

Program can prevent the injection of dll, so I don't know what I can do to bypass this.

My final goal is to hook the api call of any program.

This domains is new for me, so I'm a beginner here, if you have any resource or solution about it !

injector.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    // path to our dll
    LPCSTR DllPath = "D:\\projects\\standardinjection\\release\\testlib.dll";

    INT process_id = 14367;
    // Open a handle to target process
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, process_id);

    // Allocate memory for the dllpath in the target process
    // length of the path string + null terminator
    LPVOID pDllPath = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, strlen(DllPath) + 1,
        MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    // Write the path to the address of the memory we just allocated
    // in the target process
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pDllPath, (LPVOID)DllPath,
        strlen(DllPath) + 1, 0);

    // Create a Remote Thread in the target process which
    // calls LoadLibraryA as our dllpath as an argument -> program loads our dll
    HANDLE hLoadThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("Kernel32.dll"),
            "LoadLibraryA"), pDllPath, 0, 0);

    // Wait for the execution of our loader thread to finish
    WaitForSingleObject(hLoadThread, INFINITE);

    std::cout << "Dll path allocated at: " << std::hex << pDllPath << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    // Free the memory allocated for our dll path
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pDllPath, strlen(DllPath) + 1, MEM_RELEASE);

    return 0;
}
```

my dll

```
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    if (ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        MessageBox(0, L"Hello From testlib!", L"Hello", MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    return TRUE;
}
```

I'm currently on windows 10 x64
Coming from Unix os, so Windows is pretty new for me!

Thanks for your time !

Comment: What's the actual problem you have?

Comment: Actually, this program can only inject dll into process without any protection, it's a basic injection. I'm searching a way to hook any api call of any process, (NtCreateFile, etc.) . I don't if this can be done with simple dll, injection.

Comment: @nerap I added some info to my answer which addresses this comment, take a look and let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For 99% of injection methods, you must be able to write your code into the target process.  In order to do this, you need to be able to open a Process Handle by using [OpenProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess)() with the required [privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights).

If the process you are trying to inject to is a game with kernel mode anticheat it will block you via [ObjRegisterCallbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-obregistercallbacks).  You will need to also be in kernel mode to bypass this protection, unless they have some whitelist system you can abuse in usermode.

If the process you are trying to inject into is running as SYSTEM or a Protected Process Light process then you are in trouble there as well.  More info on that in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211120/how-do-i-elevate-permissions/58824672#58824672)

In your comments you said your goal is to hook APIs, to answer this portion of your question I would refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921054/simple-trampoline-hook/54661410#54661410) where I explain it